# Correlations between vectors in two groups (defined by: group_by)

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to make a correlation between two vectors in two different groups (defined by `group_by`). The solution needs to be based on dplyr.

My data is in the so-called CDISC format. For simplicity: here is some dummy data (note that one column ("values") holds all the data):

```
n=5
bmi<-rnorm(n=n,mean=25)
glucose<-rnorm(n=n,mean=5)
insulin<-rnorm(n=n,mean=10)
id<-rep(paste0("id",1:n),3)
myData<-data.frame(id=id,measurement=c(rep("BMI",n),rep("glucose",n),rep("insulin",n)),values=c(bmi,glucose,insulin))
```

Keeping in mind that all my functions for working with this kind of data is by using dplyr package, such as:

`myData %>% group_by(measurement) %>% summarise(mean(values), n())`

How do I get the correlation between glucose and insulin (`cor(glucose, insulin)`)? Or in a more general way: how do I get the correlation between two groups?

The following solution is obviously very wrong (but may help to understand my question):

```
myData %>% group_by(measurement) %>% summarise(cor(glucose,insulin))
```

Comment: Why not simply put the data in the wide format using `tidyr`, something like `myData %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = "measurement", value = "values") %>%
  summarise(cor = cor(x = glucose, y = insulin))
`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I had a feeling that I needed to widen my data and after seeing your results I am convinced :) thanks. This is really great.